# Regex for period around letters except for three periods (ellipsis)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to capture periods in the middle of a text (like.this).
I've written a few exceptions for numbers and quotations etc, but I can't figure out how to get it to allow three periods in the middle of a sentence (like...this).

The following should not be a match:

." .“ not...match 7.30

And the following should be a match:

is.match

Atm my regex looks like this:
`(\.[^ 0-9."“])`

Hope someone can help me as I'm really stuck.

Kind regards

Edited to make myself more clear

**Solution**

Ended up using this https://regex101.com/r/NcKJxj/1

`(?<=\p{L})(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})(?=[^ 0-9."“]\p{L})`

Comment: `^\w+\.\.\.\w+$`

Comment: Maybe you can use `\.(?!(?<=\p{L}.)\p{L})`. What is with the `(\.[^ 0-9."“])` pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this pattern `(\.[^ 0-9."“])` does not match `."` or `.“` It means the opposite, matching `.` followed by any char that is not listed in the character class.

If you don't want to match `...` but do want to match 1, 2 or 4+ dots:

```
(?<=\p{L})(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})(?=[^ 0-9."“]\p{L})
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\p{L})` Positive lookbehind, assert any letter to the left
- `(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})` Match either 1, 2 or 4+ dots
- `(?=[^ 0-9."“]\p{L})` Assert any char other than the listed in the character class followed by matching any letter

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cp%7bL%7d%29%28%3f%3a%5c.%7b1%2c2%7d%7c%5c.%7b4%2c%7d%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e+0-9.%22%e2%80%9c%5d%5cp%7bL%7d%29&i=Test%2c+med+valid+brug%2c+af+komma+og+punktum.+Det+er+fedt+nok.+%22.%22+%22%3f%22+%22%3f%22+%e2%80%9etest.%e2%80%9c+...+2%2c3%25+7.30+dette...er+en+test+dette%e2%80%a6er+en+test+dette.er+en+test+not..allowed+not....allowed+this...is+allowed)

Comment: I've written it in a stupid way, sorry. I've edited the post to be more clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: I want to match the dot that is surrounded by a letter (is.match). It is important, that it does not match any of the other characters.
I have a link for regex101, that I'm trying to make work here:
https://regex101.com/r/Q6HrHv/2
It should only match "dette.er"

Comment: I think you can match a dot, not preceded by a dot and assert not any of the listed chars at the right `(?<!\.)\.(?=[^ 0-9."“])` https://regex101.com/r/kXXAJu/1

Comment: I think I've found a way to do it:
https://regex101.com/r/Q6HrHv/9
Do you have a "cleaner" solution, otherwise I'll roll with this one :D

Comment: @oliverkea Like this for a match only `(?<=\p{L})(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})(?=[^ 0-9."“]\p{L})` https://regex101.com/r/NcKJxj/1

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Thank you so much for the help :D